# Change opacity of an Icon

Tags: flutter, dart, icons, opacity

I am trying to **change the opacity of an icon**, when it is present in the code in this format:

```
child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
```

I want to do it in the **same way you can do it with a color**:

```
color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.25),
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is there anything wrong with this approach?

```
    Icon(
      Icons.camera_alt,
      color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.25),
    )
```

Comment: Exactly, I think..this is also a possible way of doing it..so..what's wrong in it..  is it not working or what..!?

Comment: @srikanth7785 there is nothing wrong with it.. I was being sarcastic

Comment: I think sarcasm is not well portrayed in writing. I would recommend changing the wording to sound like a proper suggestion rather than sarcastic remark.

Comment: @Dharman I might keep it that way just for now.. It might not work for OP for some unexplained reason and I would like to know the reason

Answer (score 2):

There is an `Opacity` widget you can use

Example

```
 Opacity(
            opacity: 0.25,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.ac_unit
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works:

```
Icon(Icons.pause, color: Colors.white70)
```

as does this:

```
Icon(Icons.pause, color: Color(0xB3FFFFFF))
```

but this fails:

```
    Icon(Icons.pause, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(70))

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building LiveCountdownTimer(dirty, state: LiveCountdownTimerState#25b2d):
'dart:ui/painting.dart': Failed assertion: line 189 pos 12: '<optimized out>': is not true.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  CountdownTimer CountdownTimer:file:///Users/xxx/lib/screen/aaa.dart:637:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      Color.withOpacity (dart:ui/painting.dart:189:12)
```